# Ubuntu freezes when react-native run-android on emulator

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, react-native

So 
1.) I start, AVD/Genymotion

2.) run `react-native start`

3.) wait till emulator loads and react-native start

4.) its unresponsive mouse stuttering then it freezes. sometimes while finding dependencies sometiems after.

I've been searching for solutions couldn't find one. Anyone experienced this? or anyone who has any idea why this happens?

[image]

Comment: what ubuntu version you are using ?

Comment: 16.04.1 latest as of this date